# If $O(G)=17.\;$ then find total number of non-isomorphic subgroups of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't know how to find non-isomorphic subgroups of a group. Actually, I'm not clear what is meant by "non-isomorphic."

Comment: There's no convenient algorithm in general, but there's only one group of order 17, so...

Comment: Show that $G$ has very few subgroups. It is a "simple" group.

Comment: Here G has two sub groups, one of order 1 and the other of order 17. How do I verify which is non-isomorphic?

Comment: @Droy being non-isomorphic ("structurally distinct") is not a property of a single group, but of two groups. The groups you found are nonisomorphic because they have distinct orders.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you.The term 'non-isomorphic' confused me. I understand it now.

Answer (score 5):

Every group with an order $p$ where $p$ is prime is cyclic, indeed, isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$. Since $17$ is prime, it's only divisors are $1, 17$. If there are subgroups of $G$, they must be of order $1$, or order $17$.

Indeed, we have the trivial subgroup containing the identity $e_g\in G$ as its only element, and $G$ itself. Clearly $\{e_g\}\not\cong G$, since two groups whose orders differ cannot be isomorphic.